# Angular: reactive form set value from subscription

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular-reactive-forms

I am building a ticketing app for a department using a MEAN stack. A user will fill in a ticket requesting. The info will be stored on DB and then displayed on a page. A different person from the department will need to change/correct certain fields.

I have a few select fields that need to be populated with preselected info from original form data that lives in the DB.

the problem i am having is when i setting the value of a form control to the response info, i get  a "undefined" error.  I assume the dom is completing 
 before it gets to setvalue but unsure.

any advice is appreciated.

detail-wo.component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
import { WoService } from '../../../service/wo.service';
import {Wo } from '../../../models/wo.model';
.......

@Component({
..........
})
export class DetailWoComponent implements OnInit {
  wo: Wo;
  stat;
  woUpdateForm: FormGroup;
 .............

  private woId: string;

  constructor(public woService: WoService, public route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      this.woId = paramMap.get('woId');
      this.woService.getWo(this.woId).subscribe(woData => {
        this.wo = {
          _id: woData._id,
         ......
          status: woData.status,
          ....
        };
       this.stat = theis.wo.status;

      });
    });

    // form
    this.woUpdateForm = new FormGroup({
      assignment: new FormControl('No One', {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      status: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      reqtype: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      })
    });


    this.ewoUpdateForm.controls['status'].setValue(this.stat); // value from wo data from db

  }
```

detail-wo.component.html

```html
<h3>EWO Details</h3>
  <h5>EWO #: <span class="orange">{{ewo?._id}}</span></h5>

<div class="row mt-3">

  <div class="col">
    <h5>User Input</h5>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Start Date: {{wo.startDate}} </li>    
      <li class="list-group-item">Status: {{wo.status}} </li>
....
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>


<form class="mt-5 mb-5" (submit)="onUpdateWo()" [formGroup]="woUpdateForm">
  <div class="row bg border p-3 rounded">
 
.......
  <!-- Assigment -->
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label for="status">Assignment: </label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="assignment">
      <option *ngFor="let assign of assigments" value="{{assign.id}}">{{assign.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>



  <!-- Status change -->
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label for="status">Status Change </label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="status">
      <option *ngFor="let status of statuses" value="{{status.id}}">{{status.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
</form>
<code>{{ewo | json}}</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create and initialise the formGroup within your subscription to the dataService otherwise the formGroup.setValue is triggered independently to the backend call.

Furthermore, I would probably use the RxJs operator map, to combine the retrival of your queryParam and the backend call, to avoid two subscriptions within each other

Comment: In order to get rid of the nested subscription, the right operator should be `mergeMap` here, right?

Comment: if the results of the first subscription are only used in order to create the second subscription, i would recommend `switchMap` instead

Comment: I would use just map, to give back the right queryParam first, because you than could use distinctUntilChanged, so the observable only emits when ur desired queryParam changes and after that i would use a flatMap which returns ur service call and than you can subscribe.

Comment: @Jay Rich Sorry I can‘t comment on other posts yet, but your problem is not that you used reactive forms (formgroups and formcontrol) rather than templatedriven forms (ngmodel). Even if you would swap and rebuild everything with template driven forms your error would persist, because you still assign undefined to your status property since its outside the data service subscription

Comment: thanks Erbsenkoenig, that worked. I still had some formGroup errors but added a *ngIf to form to remendy

Comment: If your formGroup definition is independent of your dataService you can actually define the formGroup before the subscription to you dataService. Than you wouldn‘t need the ngIf. Sorry I was assuming in my answer your formGroup defintion depends on the data from that service but I should have asked if that‘s the case. But yeah if your dataService defines the control within your formGroup you need the ngIf around the form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `ngModel` to perform double binding to your wo property in the form? Does anything prevent you from that?

If not, you might as well double bind like this:

```
  <!-- Status change -->
  <div class="form-group col">
    <label for="status">Status Change </label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="status" [(ngModel)]="wo.status">
      <option *ngFor="let status of statuses" [value]="status">{{status.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
<!-- etc... -->
```

You may refer to this section in the angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

Comment: i tried that but i get a warning message n the console: "It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName."